# A stopwatch that ticks in a specific rate?

Tags: time

I wrote a simple stopwatch class, that begins in setting its `_start` data member to `System.getCurrentTicks()`, and when calling `stopwatch.elapsed()` it simply returns `System.getCurrentTicks() - _start`.

However I want to be able to speed up my stopwatch or slow it down. Something like `stopwatch.setSpeed(2.0f); //ticks 2x faster`, but I can't figure out what the code should be like. It might involve manipulating `_start` but I'm not sure how. I searched for this on the web and found nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: What language is this? Java? Please edit your tags.

Comment: I'm coding in C++ but why does it matter?